# Error en la conexión a fichero *.dbf

Tags: c#, dbase

Tengo que conectarme a una BBDD formada por ficheros *.dbf (Es la BBDD de una versión antigua de SAGE, un facturaplus o similar pero desconozco la versión).

Creo que es DBaseIII porque abriendo los ficheros en binario el primer *byte* es 03, y lo deduzco de [aquí](http://www.elguille.info/NET/ADONET/acceso_ficheros_dbase_vbnet_csharp.aspx), [aquí](https://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_NOTE_1_SOURCE) y de la web del [fabricante](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm)

El código con el que intento conectarme (adaptado del primer enlace que he facilitado) es:

```
using System.Data;

...


    sConn = "Driver ={ Microsoft dBASE Driver(*.dbf)}; DriverID = 277; Dbq =C:\Clientes\DBF18" 

    using (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection dbConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConn))
    {
        try
        {
            dbConn.Open();

            //Código no relevante

            dbConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al abrir la base de datos\n" + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

y siempre obtengo el mismo error: `ERROR [IM002] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especifico ningún controlador predeterminado`

¿Cómo puedo hacer la conexión?

Por otro lado, en los enlaces de microsoft para bajar [drivers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/mt490121(v=msdn.10)), son obsoletos. No se si conocéis donde podría obtenerlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al final lo he conseguido yo mismo.

[Aquí](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings) me indicaban la manera de hacerlo con DSN

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Dsn=DsnName";
conn.Open();
// Use: sql = "Select * From MyDb.dbf"
```

o sin DSN

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
    "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};" + 
    "Driverid=277;" + 
    "Dbq=C:\MyPath\";
conn.Open();
// Use: sql = "Select * From MyDb.dbf"
```

Entonces creé un DSN de tipo `Microsoft dBASE Driver(*.dbf)`. En el mismo hay que indicar la ruta en que se encuentran los ficheros *dbf.

Posteriormente revisé mi código, que quedó igual, con la única diferencia de que la cadena de conexión pasa a ser el nombre del DSN:

```
using System.Data;

...


    sConn = "nombreDSN" 

    using (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection dbConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConn))
    {
        try
        {
            dbConn.Open();

            //Código no relevante

            dbConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al abrir la base de datos\n" + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

La primera ejecución también falló, pero mostrando un error diferente, en este caso de arquitectura, ya que el driver es de 32 bits y yo estaba compilando para 64, así que cambiado eso en la configuración del proyecto, ya ha funcionado todo correctamente.

Desconozco si alguna de las pruebas anteriores que he hecho antes de hacer la pregunta, también se habría resuelto cambiando la arquitectura de compilación, pero desde luego el error que me daba era siempre el mismo, el de no encontrar el origen de datos.